# Changing MasterViewController width in UISplitViewController iOS 8 iPhone not working

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8, uisplitviewcontroller, uisplitview

So I am trying to build an iPhone app that uses a SplitView for the main screen Similar to the app Lyft or like basically this controller https://github.com/mutualmobile/MMDrawerController.

I have set up the following storyboard (I am not using SizeClasses) :

[image]

I have subclassed the SplitViewController to try to set a max width for my MasterViewController:

// File .h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface LLSplitViewController : UISplitViewController <UISplitViewControllerDelegate>

@property(nonatomic, assign) CGFloat maximumPrimaryColumnWidth NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(8_0);

@end
```

// File .m

```
@implementation LLSplitViewController

-(void)viewDidLoad{

    self.delegate = self;
    self.preferredPrimaryColumnWidthFraction = .1;
    CGRect mainScreen = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    self.maximumPrimaryColumnWidth = mainScreen.size.width - 100;
}

@end
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using this [framework](https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController) to achieve my goal.

It is not a splitcontroller but it works similar to it and it seems to be very well maintained.